# Substitute text for another with a use of a input button

Tags: javascript

I currently have the following code segment:

```
<SPAN class="defaultVal">
    <input id="defaultVal" type="submit" name="Default" value="Set Default" onclick="clickedDefaultJob();"/>
    test
</SPAN>
```

```js
function clickedDefaultJob() {
    document.getElementById("defaultVal").innerHTML = "This is default";
}
```

What i am trying to achieve is, when the user clicks the input button, the text "test" will be replaced with "This is default". This however is not working. Any ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the following sibling using [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) property, then you can use [`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue) to set its text.

```js
function clickedDefaultJob() {
  document.getElementById("defaultVal").nextSibling.nodeValue = "This is default";
}
```

```html
<SPAN class="defaultVal">
    <input id="defaultVal" type="submit" name="Default" value="Set Default" onclick="clickedDefaultJob();"/>
    test
</SPAN>
```